# CASE WHEN in combination with a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I have data that looks as follows.

| PersoonID | AttributeID | StartDate | EndDate | Verhouding |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16525 | 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-02-01 | 32 |
| 16573 | 5 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-03-01 | 78 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-07-01 | 34 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 |
| 16356 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 |

I want to tag every field which has a 'Verhouding' other than zero. This can easily be done by using a `CASE WHEN`, Like so:

```
SELECT table.*,
CASE WHEN Verhouding != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS verhouding_flag
FROM table
```

The expected result would look as follows:

| PersonID | AttributeID | StartDate | EndDate | Verhouding | verhouding_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16525 | 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 32 | 1 |
| 16573 | 5 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-05-01 | 78 | 1 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2022-05-01 | 2023-05-01 | 34 | 1 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 16356 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 | 0 |

However, in some special cases, there is a Person which has a Verhouding of 0 **AND** a verhouding other than zero. In my example, PersonID 16500 is such a case. In such a case, I also want the verhouding_flag to be 1, when Verhouding is 0. So expected result would be this:

| PersoonID | PersoonID | StartDate | EndDate | Verhouding | verhouding_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16525 | 4 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 32 | 1 |
| 16573 | 5 | 2023-04-01 | 2023-05-01 | 78 | 1 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2022-05-01 | 2023-05-01 | 34 | 1 |
| 16500 | 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 | 1 |
| 16356 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-05-01 | 0 | 0 |

I could find those special cases by for example Grouping on PersoonID, AttributeID and StartDate, and see which groups have a size larger than 1 (Which means they have multiple entries for the 'Verhouding' column).

However, I don't know how to combine a solution like that with a CASE WHEN? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on whether your RDBMS supports window functions: `CASE WHEN MAX(verhouding_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY PersoonID = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1` No `GROUP BY` needed

Comment: Agree with above... but just move the close paren to the left after PersoonID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `max()` window function here:

```
select t.*,
  Max(case when Verhouding != 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by PersoonID) verhouding_flag
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql and many other sql engines you can use window function like this:

```
SELECT
  table.*,
  CASE WHEN max(Verhouding) over(partition by PersonID) != 0 
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS verhouding_flag
FROM 
  table
```

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for window functions.

You can also join the results to aggregated table like this:

```
select
  t.*,
  case when u.mx_Verhouding <> 0 then 1 else 0 end as verhouding_flag
from 
  table t
  join (select PersonID, max(Verhouding) mx_Verhouding from table group by PersonId) u
    on t.PersonID = u.PersonID
```

In this scenario, the `case` statement is using maximum of `Verhounding` for each `PersonID` from aggregated subselect named `u`.